# Can I skip the property names in an object declaration?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

on [hapi auth tutorial](https://hapijs.com/tutorials/auth) web page I found following code:

```
const validate = async (request, username, password) => {
    const user = users[username];
    if (!user) {
        return { credentials: null, isValid: false };
    }

    const isValid = await Bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
    const credentials = { id: user.id, name: user.name };

    return { isValid, credentials }; // <=== Is this a valid js statement?
};
```

My question is about the return statement. Is that valid? What does it mean?

Comment: yes it is, as long as your browser doesn't say there is an error

Comment: returns an object ... in ES5 you'd need to write `return { isValid: isValid, credentials:credentials };` - but ES6 provides shorthand code - in other words, that code will break Internet Explorer - it's odd you didn't question `return { credentials: null, isValid: false };` ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to new ES6 shorthand syntax

```
return { isValid, credentials };
```

translates to

```
return { isValid: isValid, credentials:credentials };
```

which is valid

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can skip the property names, ECMAScript 2015 luckily allows you to simply pass in the variable inside the object and the property will automatically become whatever the variable name is.

So...

```
var1 = true;
var2 = false;

object = { var1, var2 }; // { var1: true, var2: false }
```

You are effectively returning an "anonymous" variable (object in this case), which is not part variable at that moment, but instantiated at run-time once returned.

This is also known as [shorthand property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer).

Comment: your answer looks odd now that the title of the question has changed :p

Comment: @GiamPy Sorry! I updated the title to make it more searchable. It would be better if you can address the broader question in the answer.

Comment: Done! Is it better?

Comment: btw it's called "Shorthand property name": https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer